# Mapstruct is not seeing Lombok's builder annotation using Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, lombok, mapstruct

I am trying to get Mapstruct to play nicely with Lombok's `@Builder` annotation, but I have not had success. I read through the [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1538) on Lombok's GitHub, but it seemed like mostly a discussion between the different tools' developers without any resolution for users. I have seen working Maven examples, but have not been able to dig up a working Gradle example. My code is at https://github.com/spartanhooah/spring-6-web-mvc. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your config is missing an annotationProcessor entry for lombok-mapstruct-binding.

Comment: Yup, that was it! Changing implementation to annotationProcessor fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lombok` (>= 1.18.16), `mapstruct` (>= 1.2.0), and `lombok-mapstruct-binding` (>= 0.2.0) must be present as annotation processors. It is not sufficient to include them as dependencies.